# rotate and move picture at the same moment canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to rotate and move image, but when i use .rotate(), i rotate canvas.context - with coordinate system. When i try change x-coord, i cant move object horizontally - they moves on new (diagonal) x-axis :(
[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/1ma5b4bo/3/)
How i can move it horizontally?

```
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(100, 100);
        ctx.rotate(r1/180)
        ctx.translate(-100, -100);
        ctx.drawImage(image, x1, x2, 100, 100);
        ctx.rotate(-r1/180);
        ctx.restore();
         x1 += 1;
         r1 += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using transforms to simultaneously move & rotate an image goes like this:

- Clear the canvas.
- Translate to the new coordinate where you want the image's CENTERpoint to be. Translating actually repositions the [0,0] origin of the canvas. All **new** pixels drawn on the canvas will be drawn at the new origin and any rotations will cause all **new** pixels to rotate around the new origin.
- Rotate by your desired radian angle.
- Draw the image offset by negative halfWidth & negative halfHeight. This is needed to position the image's centerpoint directly over the origin (the origin == the rotation point).

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var centerX=50;
var centerY=200;
var radianAngle=0;

var img=new Image();
img.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Npl.png";
img.onload=start;

function start(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(time){
  // request another animation frame
  if(centerX<cw){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // draw the sky
  ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  
  // translate to the new point where
  // you want the images center to be
  ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);

  // rotate the canvas
  ctx.rotate(radianAngle);

  // draw the image
  // offset by half-width & half-height
  // because img.center == centerX,centerY
  ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);

  // undo the transforms
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  // draw grass
  ctx.fillStyle='forestgreen';
  ctx.fillRect(0,200,cw,ch-200);

  // draw soil
  ctx.fillStyle='saddlebrown';
  ctx.fillRect(0,200,cw,5);

  // move 
  centerX+=.2;
  centerY+=(centerX<cw/2)?-.2:.2;

  // rotate
  radianAngle+=Math.PI/60;
}
```

```css
body{background-color:ivory; padding:10px;}
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=170></canvas>
```